# Validate Umlaut in text input with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails

does someone know how to add Umlauts to a regular expression to validate the format for a text input with rails?

I tried this but it breaks rails completely:

```
validates :first_name, :presence => true, :allow_blank => false, :format => { :with => /\A[a-z A-ZäöüÄÖÜ]+\z/}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :first_name, :presence => true, :allow_blank => false, :format => { :with => /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/}
```

Comment: Rails does not break anymore but the validation fails.

Comment: Do you have an example of a string that you want to pass the validation?

Comment: These should be valid inputs:
Straße
Gässlein

edit: you example validates but whta does [:alpha:] stand for?

Comment: Alpha means any alpha character A to Z or a to z in POSIX notation. The given regex only validates one string at a time (no blanks).

Comment: I agree, smells if you cherry pick valid umlaut chars in a text field. But if you do (which was the original assumption), then you gotta use utf8 in code and my answer is good for that :)

Comment: Right, that works. I also found an overview about the POSIX values for regex: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but make sure ruby itself knows what encoding you use in code by adding as the first line (assuming utf-8):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

let me know if it helps